# Create cookie after download file

Tags: 8, cookies

I want to create a **cookie after a file download**.

This is an extension on the existing module: https://www.drupal.org/project/file_utility

Each time you click on a download, a popup opens.
For me it is fine to have the visitors e-mail address once.
Then direct download is possible without showing the popup again on other download pages.

This part of code is not generating a cookie .. why?

**EDIT: $c_response->send(); was missing here.**

```
    $c_response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response();
    $c_response->headers->setCookie(new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie('foo', 'bar'));
    $c_response->send();

    // Get cookie value
    $c_request  = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request();
    $c_value = $c_request->cookies->get('foo');

    if($c_value) {
        \Drupal::logger('file_utility')->notice($c_value);
    } else {
        \Drupal::logger('file_utility')->notice("cookie foo is empty");
    }
```

This is the function where the download logic happens:
In this function, first I need to check if the cookie exists.
If so, direct download can start. If not, popup must be initiated.
The first time, the cookie will be empty.

```
    public function downloadAction() {
        // Get cookie value
        $c_request = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request();
        $c_value = $c_request->cookies->get('foo');
        \Drupal::logger('file_utility')->notice("cookie: " . $c_value);
        if ($c_value) {
            \Drupal::logger('file_utility')->notice($c_value);
        } else {
            \Drupal::logger('file_utility')->notice("cookie foo is empty");
        }

        /** set cookie if $c_value is empty **/        
        $c_response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response();
        $c_response->headers->setCookie(new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie('foo2', 'bar2'));
        $c_response->send();
        /** end set cookie **/

        if (!isset($_GET['f_path'])) {
            return;
        }
        // Process download.
        $f_path_encoded = \Drupal::request()->query->get('f_path');
        $full_path = base64_decode(urldecode($f_path_encoded));
        $force_download = \Drupal::request()->query->get('force_download');
        $response['file_name'] = basename($full_path);
        $uid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
        $user = User::load($uid);
        if ($user->hasPermission('file download access') && $force_download == '1') {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($response['file_name']) . '"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            // Flush system output buffer.
            flush();
        } elseif ($user->hasPermission('file download access') && $force_download == '0') {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($full_path);
            $response->send();
            die;
        } else {
            $url = $full_path;
            if (strpos($full_path, 'sites/default') !== FALSE) {
                throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
            } else {
                $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
                $response->send();
                die;
            }
        }

    }
```

**Extra: Can I set the cookie after the formsubmit?**
I found that you can add a response to a form_state but that is also not setting the cookie. I have added the first 3 lines in below function, but that is not working at the moment.

```
     /**
     * AJAX callback handler that displays any errors or a success message.
     */
    public function submitUserInfoFormAjax(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $c_response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response();
        $c_response->headers->setCookie(new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie('john', 'do'));
        $form_state->setResponse($c_response);

        $response = new AjaxResponse();
        $value = $form_state->getValues();
        //$name = $value['name'];
        $email = $value['email'];
        $user_ip = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] : \Drupal::request()->getHost();
        $f_path_encoded = \Drupal::request()->query->get('f_path');
        $f_path = base64_decode(urldecode($f_path_encoded));
        $force_download = \Drupal::request()->query->get('force_download');
        // If there are any form errors, re-display the form.
        if ($form_state->hasAnyErrors()) {
            $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#status_message_div', $form));
        } else {
            $status = parent::save($form, $form_state);

            $entity = $this->entity;
            $response->addCommand(new RedirectCommand('/filedownload?f_path=' . $f_path_encoded . '&force_download=' . $force_download));
            $response->addCommand(new CloseModalDialogCommand());
        }

        return $response;
    }
```

**Important notice for making the cookie available for javascript:**

httponly must be set to false in the constructor.

```
$response->headers->setCookie(new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie('_john', 'do', time() + 3600, '/', '.yourdomain.com', false, false));
```

Comment: You have to send the response to get a browser to set the cookie. Then on the _next_ request, you can get cookies from that request. Creating an arbitrary response and request won't do anything, they're not connected to one another

Comment: The cookie is now created, but that throws up an other issue: the function is also sending out a RedirectResponse. But that is not working anymore because the HttpFoundation Response is already send ...

Comment: Yeah, I confess I don't really understand what your code would be attempting to do, I thought it was just representative rather than identical. You can't set a cookie and read that same cookie in the same request, it's not conceptually feasible. You'd never need to either, because if you have a variable that you want to set as a cookie, you can do so when you send the response, at the end of the request, and the variable is still available earlier on in that same request. It sounds like what you need to do is override the controller that serves the file, set your cookie there, then hook into..

Comment: ..the other part of the code, the one that decides whether to show the popup, and check the cookie there

Comment: The part of the code to get the cookie, was representative. I know that it doesn't make sense. I have added the function where the download logic happens. I guess I cannot override the controller because the class itself (FileUtilityController) serves the file in above function downloadAction()?

Comment: Maybe you can better use drupal private temp store for this job: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21TempStore%21PrivateTempStore.php/class/PrivateTempStore/8.7.x

Comment: That could be a solution if the private temp is not deleted after a user session has ended.  I read that you can set an expire property. I guess it will not be deleted then? Clearing the cache is not affecting the private temp, that is ok. I will test it.

Comment: It is not an option to use the Private Temp. I need a cookie because I need to check the cookie in a javascript function that was implemented by the module owner. Why is the setResponse not working when adding to the $form_state?

Comment: Cookies work, I have used them sparingly. You can set them in a request or response but they are not readable until the next request from the browser. Also, if you are in Pantheon or Acquia, your cookie names have to follow certain naming conventions to be able to be passed from the browser to the application and vice versa. I am not entirely certain you can set a form state response but return an ajax command in the same method. You might be setting the response on the form, but its just setting the info and never executed.

Comment: Well I am stuck on this. I need help with less abstract solutions on this. I've tried to create a hook_form_alter with an extra submit_handler, but it is always the same problem. Or the response in not executed (via form_state) or if you send it directly, the rest of the function is no longer executed. I guess I am not the first one that need to set a cookie after some event ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem in your current code is that you're overwriting the response.
You should add the cookie to the default AjaxResponse instead:

```
public function submitUserInfoFormAjax(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $response = new AjaxResponse();

    $response->headers->setCookie(new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie('john', 'do'));

    $value = $form_state->getValues();
    //$name = $value['name'];
    $email = $value['email'];
    $user_ip = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] : \Drupal::request()->getHost();
    $f_path_encoded = \Drupal::request()->query->get('f_path');
    $f_path = base64_decode(urldecode($f_path_encoded));
    $force_download = \Drupal::request()->query->get('force_download');
    // If there are any form errors, re-display the form.
    if ($form_state->hasAnyErrors()) {
        $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#status_message_div', $form));
    } else {
        $status = parent::save($form, $form_state);

        $entity = $this->entity;
        $response->addCommand(new RedirectCommand('/filedownload?f_path=' . $f_path_encoded . '&force_download=' . $force_download));
        $response->addCommand(new CloseModalDialogCommand());
    }

    return $response;
}
```